# Postgresql with docker: FATAL: could not read permissions of directory: Permission denied

Tags: postgresql, docker, virtualbox

I'm trying to dockerize a postgresql server while persisting the data on the host. My container works fine without mounting volumes from the host, but it crashes because of permissions with those volumes:

`FATAL:  could not read permissions of directory "/var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main": Permission denied`

my docker run command is

```
docker run -p 54332:5432 -v `pwd`/volumes/postgres/log:/var/log/postgresql -v `pwd`/volumes/postgres/lib:/var/lib/postgresql mypostgres`
```

and my docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install wget --assume-yes

RUN echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt trusty-pgdg main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list &&\
    wget --quiet -O - http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -

RUN apt-get update &&\
    apt-get install postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1 postgresql-contrib --assume-yes

RUN mkdir /home/postgres/  && \
    chown -R postgres /home/postgres

USER postgres

# make .pgpass file
RUN echo "127.0.0.1:5432:database:username:password" >> /home/postgres/.pgpass

RUN /etc/init.d/postgresql start &&\
    psql --command "CREATE USER docker WITH SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'docker';" &&\
    createdb -O docker docker

# Adjust PostgreSQL configuration so that remote connections to the
# database are possible. 
RUN echo "host all  all    0.0.0.0/0  md5" >> /etc/postgresql/9.4/main/pg_hba.conf

RUN echo "listen_addresses='*'" >> /etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf

# Expose the PostgreSQL port
EXPOSE 5432

# Add VOLUMEs to allow backup of config, logs and databases
VOLUME  ["/etc/postgresql", "/var/log/postgresql", "/var/lib/postgresql"]

# Set the default command to run when starting the container
CMD ["/usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin/postgres", "-D", "/var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main", "-c", "config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf"]
```

Comment: What is the OS/distribution of the host system?

Comment: It's a ubuntu server, running into virtualbox since I develop under windows. I thought this could be due to some mounted folder permissions but have not been able to fix that by copying the files, changing the permission, ...

Answer (score 1):

This happens because:

- you are on Windows running a VirtualBox VM, itself running the docker host
- you are mounting a docker volume for a directory which is shared between Windows and the docker host

Try this:

```
docker run -p 54332:5432 -v /tmp/volumes/postgres/log:/var/log/postgresql -v /tmp/volumes/postgres/lib:/var/lib/postgresql mypostgres
```

it should work as `/tmp` is not a path shared by VirtualBox with the Windows host.

Comment: thanks, it solves the permission issue. However, it still isn't working, I have an error because some directory doesn't exists: 
` FATAL:  data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main" does not exist`

Comment: sorry to hear that. I add this issue myself a few weeks ago and this did the trick. There must be something else in your case. Just to be sure, have you also tried with a path which isn't `/tmp` (since `/tmp` has very special permissions)?

Comment: yes, I tried pulling the files from git, and running everything from the home directory, but the error is the same