# initdb.sql not running in Windows Server 2016 or 2019 in Docker

Tags: windows, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, init

I installed Docker EE on Windows Server 2016 and 2019.  I am spinning up a PostgreSQL container and have an initdb.sql script to initialize the database.

I am using Windows containers, and have tested the script both in `docker` and `docker-compose` on Windows 10 in Windows Containers mode.  The moment I move it to Windows Server 2016/2019, the database spins up but it does not run the `initdb.sql` script.

Here is my `docker-compose`

```
version: "3"

networks:
  localnetwork:

services:

  postgres_db:
    image: stellirin/postgres-windows:12-1809
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - .\admin\${ENV:-dev}\dbms\init:C:\docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - localnetwork
```

How do I get Windows Server 2016/2019 to run the initdb.sql?  I cannot `docker exec` into the container either because it returns `Access is denied.`

Note, `Access is denied` is also the case in Windows 10.  But I can use Docker Desktop's interface to somehow get into the container to check.  Docker EE has no Docker Desktop so this cannot be done.

Comment: Does the container report any error in the logs? What did you try to `exec`? I mean, could you indicate the `docker exec` command you are trying to run? Did you try `docker exec -it <container id> powershell` or  `docker exec -it <container id> cmd`? Perhaps the error could be motivated with something related to the volume mount, perhaps for any reason the `initdb.sql` script is not being copied to the container.

Comment: Hi jccampanero, I tried running `docker exec -it <container id> powershell`, but the image does not have PowerShell so it was invalid. Then, I tried `docker exec it <container id> :C/` and that is where it got access denied.  I was experiencing this both on WS2019 and W10, however, using Docker Desktop on W10, I was still able to login to the container CLI.  I did try to copy initdb just to `:C/` and did a `command: dir` to print out the files on `:c\` during container init and initdb was there.  Additionally, the `dir` also showed that `C:\docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` is a folder on WS2019.

Comment: There were no logs, the init logs were identical to the ones I got on W10, minus the logs for the generation of the tables from `initdb.sql`

Comment: Hi @RuiNian. Sorry for the late reply. Thank you very much for the feedback. And, did you try `docker exec -it <container id> cmd`? The important think is to check whether the `initdb.sql` file is in the `C:\docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` or not. As a workaround, to avoid some possible error related to the mounted volume, you could try to create a very basic `Dockerfile` and copy initdb.sql: `FROM stellirin/postgres-windows:12-1809

WORKDIR /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

COPY initdb.sql ./
` . Then use this dockerfile in your docker compose. Please, could you try? It may give you some clues

Comment: about the problem.

Comment: Were you able to test the suggested `COPY` approach?

Answer (score 0):

> this happens when the 1a) data directory for the postgres windows user account does not have access or 1b) you are mounting a docker volume for a directory which is shared between Windows and the docker host from user [thomas here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31145922/6085193)

#### 1a. To check permissions on PG_DATA directory run this

```
// check your dir access
cacls "c:\YourPath\pgdata\dir"
```

#### 1b) issue if the directory is shared between windows and docker host

> `docker run -p 54332:5432 -v /tmp/volumes/postgres/log:/var/log/postgresql -v /tmp/volumes/postgres/lib:/var/lib/postgresql mypostgres`

#### 2. Also please check, if you have a previous crashed file

Manually remove the postmaster.pid file at `\postgres\directory\postmaster.pid` and start it again, then it should be fine.

#### 3. From your container you have to export/publish ports to your host with the publish command [`-p`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose) option :

```
docker run -it -v D:/postgres:/home/dump --name some_postgres -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root -d postgres
```

#### 4. check your fire wall rules

[image]

> The easiest way to fire up docker with postgres & a [nice ref to help you](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Change_the_default_PGDATA_directory_on_Windows)

```
docker run --name postgres-db -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=docker -p 5432:5432 -d postgres
```

---

Maybe easier to pull a fresh image

```
Pull down the latest [Postgres image from the Docker Hub][4]
Set the environment variable for password to 'docker'
Create a database, let's call it 'world'
Use a sql dump file to create the table schema and populate it with data
```

---